# How to set the span context on the cnosdb client side？

Tags: database, cnosdb

I turned on trace according to the documentation https://docs.cnosdb.com/zh/latest/reference/config.html#trace, but each of my requests will be traced. I hope that the collection can be personalized. I see that there is a configuration item `auto_generate_span`, but after I configure it, how to set the client to determine me Which requests are tracked?